# Expose kubernetes to wireguard peers

Tags: kubernetes, wireguard

I have a DO VPS serving as WireGuad server.

I have a few devices in that network (10.252.1.0/24) and one computer runs Kubernetes (my home server) with node IP 172.18.0.2 and VPN IP 10.252.1.3

I have tried to forward all connections except port 22 from 10.252.1.3 to 127.18.0.2 but I don't feel it's working.

```
## Forward TCP traffic from source IP 10.252.1.3 on ports 1-21 and 23-65535
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 10.252.1.3 -p tcp --dport 1:21 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.2
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 10.252.1.3 -p tcp --dport 23:65535 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.2

# Forward UDP traffic from source IP 10.252.1.3 on ports 1-21 and 23-65535
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 10.252.1.3 -p udp --dport 1:21 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.2
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 10.252.1.3 -p udp --dport 23:65535 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.2
```

on the kubernetes host if i curl 172.18.0.2:port the response is there, but when i curl 10.252.1.3:port it refuses "Couldn't connect to server"

also after applying iptables curl and kubectl stopped working on the host.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

My goal is to have a VPS server so i can connect to my home network and access services running on kubernetes my home server. this is also something educational for me, to learn kubernetes

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current iptables rules are using DNAT on the VPS and it redirects incoming traffic from specific ports on the VPS (10.252.1.3) to your Kubernetes node (172.18.0.2). DNAT can work in some scenarios but it might interfere with established connections or services running on the VPS itself.

To achieve your goal of accessing services on the Kubernetes node from your home network devices connected through the WireGuard VPN, you actually need SNAT (Source Network Address Translation) on the Kubernetes node. SNAT modifies the source address of outgoing packets from the Kubernetes node, making it appear as if they originated from the VPS (10.252.1.3) on your home network.

Also check if other firewall rules or services are blocking incoming traffic on the Kubernetes node. You can temporarily disable iptables rules (`sudo iptables -F`) to see if it resolves the issue with `curl` and `kubectl`.

For more iptables advanced configuration options, see this [document](https://netfilter.org/documentation/).

Comment: Thank you I will try the SNAt when I will have some time, in the end (just forgot to close the question) I have managed to solve it by configuring k8s to bind exposed services (and ingress) to 0.0.0.0 on host, and now I can access the exposed ports over VPN without iptables